# Change API version

Tags: android

I get the error:

```
ERROR: Application requires API version 11. Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2).
```

How can I change the API version of my app, I am using eclipse.

Thanks

Comment: +1. this is already answered here.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8699271/744859

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit the `android:minSdkVersion` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file.  Set this value to the lowest level you are targeting...in this case 8.

If you want to compile against a higher API level, but allow the app to run on 2.2 devices, leave the minimum at 8, and add a `android:targetSdkVersion` parameter set to 11.

HTH

Comment: Like this:  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="11"/> So this should run on phones and tablets?