# ERROR: Application requires API version 14. Device API version is 13 (Android 3.2.1)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I am following a tutorial for creating a simple application in **Android**, and compiling it with **Eclipse** on **Linux**.

The problem is that when I first created the project, I used the target **API 14**. But my tablet only has **API 13**, so I have changed it in `project > properties > android` to **API 13**. Even though I still get next the error:

```
ERROR: Application requires API version 14. Device API version is 13 (Android 3.2.1)
```

Why is this happening if I *have changed the compilation target*?

Comment: Very common error when starting with android

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Android creates the manifest with minSdkVersion, that doesn't change automatically when you change the properties.

Change the line inside Android manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
```

and put 13 instead of 14.

Answer (score 8):

Open AndroidMainfestFile.xml change the SdkVersion there.

Answer (score 6):

Use as below or remove the entire line for auto detection of API level

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an useful [explanation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html) of versioning in Android. Basically android enforces the system compatibility as expressed by the minSdkVersion in the manifest.

> **android:minSdkVersion** — The minimum version of the Android platform on
>   which the application will run, specified by the platform's API Level
>   identifier.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to note. Be sure after you have made this change that you "Clean" your project and recompile or it will not take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that after updating API of your emulator the old version of the emulator should be shutdown if it is running. That was in my case.