# Incorrect Device API version in android

Tags: android

I am new to android. In my application I tried to call a SOAP web service, but when I run the project it says: Required API is 9,but Device API is 8.

What can I do for that.

Comment: set your project api to 8 from androidmanifest file.

Comment: Hi  Moe Jo  sorry, I cant able to get any emulator in your link.Please give some details.

Comment: Hi  Herry  i tried that also it also throws some error.

Comment: @Herry, that wouldn't solve the problem, as setting the project to API level 8 won't magically make that feature available before API level 9

Comment: @subburaj, the emulator is embedded in the Android SDK. you can get it by running the `Run Configurations` and in the dialog going to the 'target` and choosing an Emulator. for more, look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506777/how-to-run-android-emulator-automatically-from-eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506777/how-to-run-android-emulator-automatically-from-eclipse)

Comment: I think this is answered here.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8699271/744859

Answer (score 2):

This means that a method or class you have used in your code wasn't added to Android until API revision 9 (Gingerbread, see [this list](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html)).

If you want your app to run on a lower API version, you'll have to either remove that call, or use reflection ([described here if you need it](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)) to check for it's availability. Either way you'll have to find another way to do what you're wanting on lower API versions.